# angular2 - вызов formControlName внутри компонента

Tags: form, angular2

Не могу понять почему `formControlName` не хочет работать внутри другого компонента.

Рабочий пример:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm">
   <app-form-group [field]="'email'">
       <input type="text" [formControlName]="'email'" />
   </app-form-group>
</form>
```

Написал для input-a обертку, которая будет подхватывать название поля из родительского app-form-group дабы не дублировать 'email'. Angular стал падать, жалуясь что родительским элементом должен быть элемент с директивой [formGroup], хотя даже в рабочем примере выше видно что form является input-у предком но не родителем.
Чтобы откинуть вопросы с логикой моей обертки сгенерировал пустой компонент и поместил в него точто такой же инпут как и в примере но это не работает, получилось такое:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="myForm">
   <app-form-group [field]="'email'">
       <app-control></app-control>
   </app-form-group>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему использованием [formControl] директивны. 
В итоге внедряю название поля из родительского app-form-group и сам объект формы внедряю из директивы [formGroup]